# Call method after no request for while api rest c#

Tags: c#, angular, rest, api, request

Is there any way to call a method / function in an API rest in C# if it is a specific time without any request?

The goal would be to know when a person would have left the interface prematurely (or in case of power failure).
Or in case of prolonged inactivity.

In my case : the front is in angular4

Comment: webapi is state less right ? then how come you get that information

Comment: I don't understand your meaning, but what I wanted to say is a way to call a function if none request is on fo a while

Comment: Your UI (i.e. JS) will need to ping the server periodically. The server will need to store the last ping time.

Comment: I can not store anything in the api because it is restfull. Or I don't know how to do it...

Comment: @Rapido - you need to store it in db ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In other words, you tring to achive the ability to commuincate with the client from the server.
It's called [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API), there are some implimation for that.

The best implantation for C# WebSockets is [SignalR](https://www.asp.net/signalr)

The way you should use it' is that in your server you would 'ping' all your connected clients, and those who are not responding, assume as disconnected (you might add some delay to prevent unwanted disconnections)

The second option, is to created an interval on your client, and each time send an 'ping' to the server that the client 'is alive', that's pretty messy and i don't like that approach, but its little bit easier.

Good Luck!